# Why no Stack Exchange page for Microsoft Windows?

Tags: discussion

I had some issue on **Window 7**, so I tried to search stack exchange (where else I could go).

But to my surprise there is no Stack Exchange page for **Windows**.

Is there any specific reason for that? Why stack exchange has not included Q&A site for Microsoft Windows platform when there are pages for other UNIX/Linux platforms?

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com

Comment: I see you have an account on [SU]. Maybe your question would be appropriate there?

Comment: AFAIK Super User is supposed to cover Windows.

Comment: @Pëkka It's got a tag for Windows in general, and tags for various Windows versions. But since the OP has an account on [SU] and apparently logged in there only a few hours ago, he/she probably knows that. So - OP, is there a reason your question might not be appropriate for Super User?

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 questions would be on-topic on [SuperUser.](https://superuser.com/)

There's no single SE site for "Windows," because server/administration questions are on-topic on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) while end-user/workstation questions make sense on SuperUser.  There's actually only one SE site for a specific Linux platform, [AskUbuntu,](https://askubuntu.com/) and that's a special case: it's a sort of joint venture with Canonical.

Comment: and programming for Windows is appropriate on SO...

Comment: Aren't you forgetting [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby I wouldn't call Unix&Linux a "specific" platform... there's no single "owner" the way there is for Ubuntu or Windows.

Comment: @Ward: I wouldn't think in the terms of "owner" but rather "very specific topic".

Answer (score 0):

There is a proposed [Microsoft Stack Exchange Site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60388/microsoft) on Area 51.